# xcode command line compilation

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, compilation

I have to use command line to build a Debug and Release versions.
the build process is fine, I have a little problem is that while making a debug version I need the debug URLS(the exposed service on Dev Servers) and for Release for Compilation different URLs should be compiled and need to be done via Command line.

what should I be reading or doing for this.

thanks
Aleena Shah

Comment: Do you have the different URLs working when you compile from the Xcode UI?

Answer (score 0):

For release, Xcode defines `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS`, but does not specify Posix's `NDEBUG`. First, you should add `-DDEBUG=1` to debug builds and `-DNDEBUG=1` to release builds to account for Apple's omissions.

Then you can use macros:

```
#if defined(NDEBUG)
# define MY_URL http://foo.com
#else
# define MY_URL http://bar.com
#endif
```

You could also do something like:

```
#if defined(NDEBUG)
  static const string MY_URL = "http://foo.com";
#else
  static const string MY_URL = "http://bar.com";
#endif
```

`DEBUG` is not standard per Posix, but you will find a lot of libraries turn diagnostics on when the symbol is defined. Diagnostics during debugging is good since they will help you find mistakes in your code.

OWASP has an in-depth treatment of the subject for the security minded at [C-Based Toolchain Hardening](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/C-Based_Toolchain_Hardening).